# Adding the AWGN to the data makes its covariance matrix always positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

I'm working on a numerical method that estimates direction-of-arrivals in antenna arrays.

I realized that every time I add the AWGN (Additive white Gaussian noise) to a data (which is a matrix), its (complex) covariance matrix (which is **positive semi-definite** by nature), turns into a **positive definite** matrix. I ran thousands of experiments in MATLAB to verify that. I would like to know if there is any correlation or any proof relating to it?

Additionally, my MATLAB code to generate the noise is:

```
noise = (randn(size(rxWaveform)) + 1i*randn(size(rxWaveform)))*std2(rxWaveform)/db2mag(10);
rxWaveform = rxWaveform + noise;
covmat = (1/samples)*rxWaveform*(rxWaveform');
```

*rxWaveform* is the data matrix and *covmat* is the (complex) covariance matrix.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How big are your matrices? For an extreme case, consider the $1\times 1$ zero matrix, which is positive semidefinite. Adding Gaussian noise to this scalar would have 50% chance of making it positive definite? --- By the way, are you adding noise to the *covariance matrix* or to the data it was calculated from?

Comment: Hello, I'm adding AWGN to the covariance matrix. It's usually small, like 6x6 or at most 10x10. But, is it a probability? Or does it always end up being a positive definite? If so, how can we prove it (any link or paper)? Thanks.

Comment: Adding noise destroys symmetry, so definiteness is not really meaningful anymore - or do you do anything to preserve symmetry?

Comment: @TiagoTroccoli - It has to be a probability, because you're doing something probabilistically, aren't you? If the white noise just happened (by chance) to consist entirely of zeros then you're not changing the covariance matrix, so it will still just be positive *semi*definite. And can you clarify *exactly* how you are changing the covariance matrix? (This is why there is confusion in these comments -- the details matter here.) Are you adding random noise to each entry independently? Are you adding the same noise to the (i,j)-entry as the (j,i)-entry? Are you adding noise to diagonal entries?

Comment: @NathanielJohnston Haaa no! I reviewed my code, I add the **AWGN to the data**, and afterward, I calculate its covariance matrix. I edited my question and included the MATLAB code. So, basically, when I add the AWGN to the data, its covariance matrix was always positive definite for 8000 experiments. Is it sheer luck or does AWGN make covariance matrix positive definite?

Comment: @NathanielJohnston, also, consider non-zero AWGN since, in wireless communication noise is always present.

Comment: @TiagoTroccoli --- correct me if I'm wrong, but your noisy covariance matrix is still of the form $AA^\ast$, so by construction each of its eigenvalues is $\geq 0$; it is a random matrix, for any sensible distribution of your random perturbation the probability that an eigenvalue is identically zero vanishes, so the noisy covariance matrix is positive definite.